# Messed up file permissions in /home directory godaddy cpanel

Tags: php, permissions, exec, chmod

Ok so I kind of messed up a few of my websites by using the below script, I am getting the following error on all websites:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an     ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The code that messed everything up!

```
    <?php

exec ("find / -type d -exec chmod 0750 {} +");
exec ("find / -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +");

?>
```

Comment: Can you not log in via ssh?

Comment: is that the only way?

Comment: If so that means I have to setup ssh which may take a while since I never use it..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are rewriting the permission for the root path. I've already used GoDaddy and this permission rewriting maybe is not allowed. Try to rewrite the permission manually from the cPanel file manager.

Comment: If it was not allowed then my websites wouldn't be down

Comment: Sorry, I explained it not in a right way. Try to chmod 0755, it could solve the issue.

Comment: I have also changed all the files and folders back to 0666 and 0755 respectively, no change on the websites being down though, and theres no way for me to run the script again as I cannot access the script via url

Answer (score 0):

With the first line you  changed permission to your directories to :
`User:read write execute;` `Group:read execute;` `World:---`
And with the other one you changed file permission to :
`User:read write;` `Group:read;` `World:read`

My suggestion is to login trought FTP, or SSH and change file permissions to the original ones.
You can activate ssh connection from your cpanel, then trought an ssh client such putty, you can acces to your server and try to change file permission.

If this does not works, try to login in your godaddy account, go to cpanel and click on 'file manager' open your root and check the permission of your files. Permissions are listed at the rigth of the table near the file type description. If the files permissions are wrong try to change them and see if anything happens, else i reccomed to contact godaddy support, them would surely help you.